# Mongodb server not connecting with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is the primary program of node.js to connect MongoDB. Copied from the internet because my actual code not working, so I am trying this one. This raises the same issue.

Problem with this code or in my local machine. When I ran the program, it got stuck or in any loop, and after a few minutes, it shows timeout, without any further detailed error message.

const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

```
// Connection URL
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

// Database Name
const dbName = "myproject";

// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(url);

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
client.connect(function (err) {

console.log("Connected successfully to server");
const db = client.db(dbName);
client.close();
});
```

Try to connect with atlas or local mongoDB compass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check this code**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

connectionUri = `mongodb://${config.get('server:mongodb:username')}:${config.get('server:mongodb:password')}@${config.get('server:mongodb:host')}:${config.get('server:mongodb:port')}/${config.get('server:mongodb:name')}?authSource=admin`;
mongoose.connect(connectionUri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

replace with your username and password

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code for the DB connection.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
try {
  mongoose.connect(
    "mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject",
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    },
    function (err, db) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("MongoDB Database Connection Error", err);
      } else {
        console.log("MongoDB Connection Done!!");
      }
    }
  );
} catch (e) {
  console.log(" ~ file: mongodb.js ~ line 24 ~ e", e);
}
```

Comment: And also make sure you are using a mongoose library for the NodeJS.

Comment: Why use mongoose when this has to work the offical mongodb module?

Comment: Not working for me. Show the below error.

MongoDB Database Connection Error MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Connection.openUri (c:\Users\91787\mongoose\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:825:32)

Comment: This error is received because your MongoDB service has been stopped or maybe crashed. first, check if your MongoDB service is running or not in your system, and if your service is running then check the database port it is running on 27017 or anything else.